# How can I add SSL in keycloak in docker

Tags: ssl, certificate, docker

I'm having an issue adding SSL certificate to Keycloak that is running on docker.
I bought an SSL Certificate from Godaddy, but don't know how to add Keycloak on docker.
I was looking through Google but nothing found yet.

Can someone of you help me with that please?

Here's the code of Dockerfile of Keycloak:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:4.6.0.Final

WORKDIR /opt/jboss/keycloak

COPY realm-export.json /opt/jboss/keycloak/

EXPOSE 8443

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.import=realm-export.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"]
```

And here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  keycloak:
    build: "./Keycloak + actibook-app client import"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-postgres
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=${KEYCLOAK_IMPORT}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSW}
      - POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR= keycloak-postgres
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"

  traefik:
    build: ./traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

- Download your GD-Cert as ZIP
- Unpack it
- cat {[[a-f0-9],gd}*.crt > yourdomain.chained.crt

Copy the private key you used to generate the Certs (e.g. your.priv.key) and yourdomain.chained.crt to your server. e.g. to /opt/jboss/keycloak/certs

Add a "volumes" section to services/keycloak

```
services:
  keycloak:
    volumes:             
      - /opt/jboss/keycloak/certs/yourdomain.chained.crt:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - /opt/jboss/keycloak/certs/your.priv.key:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
```